# Object to follow mouse pointer unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm busy working on something that uses a RTS style camera and I want an object to follow the mouse cursor but stay at the same Y-axes at all times. The camera location is set to 0, 15, -15

I've been playing with it for a while now and this is the best that I can come up with:

```
Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(5);
transform.position = point;
print (point);
```

Any help would would be appreciated.

Comment: You've not explained whether the code works or not, what's the issue with the code you have?

Comment: From what I'm guessing you are asking, is that you need to set point.y to the objects previous y position, before applying it to transform.position. Ex: point.y = transform.postion.y;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but you need to use that ray to raycast onto something to get the world position.

Since its an rts i assume the terrain is somewhat level in which case it would be easy to place a plane at the desired height. If thats not the case i recommend following @The Ryan advice and store the previous y value.

In either case you need to put the thing you raycast against in a separate layer from your other stuff so you dont move things on top of other units

```
Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
{
    float oldY = transform.position.y;
    transform.position.Set(hit.point.x, oldY, hit.point.z);
}
```